# How do I set the position of a item in a Gtk Stack?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I need to be able to designate the order which stacks go into a Gtk Stack. For example if I have a stack with the pages Welcome and Editor already added how do I add a Settings stack in between the other two?

Is there something simple I'm missinglike inserting items to a Gtk.Listbox? I'm using python and pygobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately GTK documentation can be tricky to follow. And most pygtk references don't reflect the object nature of widgets. From my experience to find something it's easiest to start with [Gnome developer](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) and then look around how it translates to the bind library (pygtk, gtkmm, etc) you are using.

In [GtkStack child properties](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html#GtkStack--c-position) you can see that there is a property for `position` of a child in GtkStack.
Then, in [GtkContainer](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Container.html#child-properties) you can find that in order to set child properties, you need to use the [function from GtkContainer](https://athenajc.gitbooks.io/python-gtk-3-api/content/gtk-group/gtkcontainer.html#childsetproperty), instead of one directly in GtkStack. So it should be something like (untested):
`stack_widget.child_set_property(settings_widget, 'position', 1)`